# PostgreSQL interval subtraction

Tags: postgresql, intervals, postgresql-10

I've tried to subtract interval from timestamp, but I've got a wrong result in comparison to days via subtracting 2 dates.

E.g.:

```
select 
  (now::date - past::date) as days,
  (now::date - past::date) / 365.25 as years,
  justify_interval(now - past::date) as interval_test
from (
  select '2020-09-17 00:00:01'::timestamp as now, '2010-09-17 00:00:01'::timestamp as past
) b;
```

gives results:

- 3653 days
- 10.0013 years
- '10 years **1 mon 23 days**' interval test

Could anyone help me to understand what is wrong with subtracting?

When I do it vice versa, it's ok:

```
select 
  (past::date + 3653)::date,
  (past + interval '10 years')::date,
  (past + 10*interval '1 year')::date,
  (past + 10*12*interval '1 month')::date
from (
  select '2020-09-17 00:00:01'::timestamp as now, '2010-09-17 00:00:01'::timestamp as past
) b;
```

all results give the same date **'2020-09-17'**

What I do wrong?

I am using PostgreSQL 10.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with subtracting. It is just that `justify_interval` doesn't do what you seem to expect. `justify_interval` uses 30 day months and 24 hour days. So 12 months becomes only 360 and 10 years only 3600 days. Leaving 53 days which is 1 (30 day) month and 23 days.

#### Edit

The `justify_interval` documentation on [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html) page refers to `justify_days` and `justify_hours` which are directly above it which do mention the use of 30 days months and 24 hour days.

The justify functions do have to make these assumption because the interval type is a general length of time (it has no specific start and end). So the justify functions does not know over which specific months the interval was originally calculated.

The age function however does not take an interval it takes an end and a start so it actually knows which specific months and years are in that period.

Comment: I didn't find it in documentation, but lot of thanks. I've used age() instead of justify_interval and it seems age() provide good results. Do you know why is different behavior between age and justify_interval?